# Is there a good way to simplify this expression?

Tags: calculus, polynomials, continuity, piecewise-continuity

## The Short Version

Is there a way to simplify this expression?

$$
\left(\left(\left(d × \left(\frac{j}{2}\right)^2\right)^2 − \frac{1}{27} × \left(\frac{j^2}{2 s}\right)^6\right)^\frac{1}{2} + d × \left(\frac{j}{2}\right)^2\right)^\frac{1}{3}
 + \frac{1}{3} × \left(\frac{j^{2}}{2 s}\right)^2 × \left(\left(\left(d × \left(\frac{j}{2}\right)^2\right)^2 − \frac{1}{27} × \left(\frac{j^2}{2 s}\right)^6\right)^\frac{1}{2} + d × \left(\frac{j}{2}\right)^2\right)^\frac{−1}{3}
 − \frac{j^2}{2 s}
$$

Specifically, I'd like to condense the cube root portion and the inverse cube root portion into a single root, if possible.

## The Longer Version

We have five positive-valued variables:

- $s_{max}$
- $j_{max}$
- $a_{max}$
- $v_{max}$
- $d_{max}$

We also have the function $\operatorname{Min}(n_1,\, n_2,\, …,\, n_k)$, which returns the input with the lowest value.

Finally, we have three variables whose values are each based on combinations of the previously-defined variables:

$$
j_{limit}\,=\,{\operatorname{Min}\begin{pmatrix}
\left(j_{max} × \frac{s_{max}^0}{0!}\right)^\frac{1}{1},\\
\left(a_{max} × \frac{s_{max}^1}{1!}\right)^\frac{1}{2},\\
\left(v_{max} × \frac{s_{max}^2}{2!}\right)^\frac{1}{3},\\
\left(d_{max} × \frac{s_{max}^3}{3!}\right)^\frac{1}{4}
\end{pmatrix}}
$$

$$
a_{limit}\,=\,{\operatorname{Min}\begin{pmatrix}
a_{max},\\
\left(v_{max} × j_{limit} + \left(\frac{j_{limit}^2}{2 s_{max}}\right)^2\right)^\frac{1}{2} - \frac{j_{limit}^2}{2 s_{max}},\\
\left(\left(\left(d_{max} × \left(\frac{j_{limit}}{2}\right)^2\right)^2 − \frac{1}{27} × \left(\frac{j_{limit}^2}{2 s_{max}}\right)^6\right)^\frac{1}{2} + d_{max} × \left(\frac{j_{limit}}{2}\right)^2\right)^\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} × \left(\frac{j_{limit}^{2}}{2 s_{max}}\right)^2 × \left(\left(\left(d_{max} × \left(\frac{j_{limit}}{2}\right)^2\right)^2 − \frac{1}{27} × \left(\frac{j_{limit}^2}{2 s_{max}}\right)^6\right)^\frac{1}{2} + d_{max} × \left(\frac{j_{limit}}{2}\right)^2\right)^\frac{−1}{3} − \frac{j_{limit}^2}{2 s_{max}}
\end{pmatrix}}
$$

and

$$
v_{limit}\,=\,{\operatorname{Min}\begin{pmatrix}
v_{max},\\
\left(d_{max} × a_{limit} + \left(\frac{a_{limit}^2}{2 j_{limit}}\right)^2\right)^\frac{1}{2} - \frac{a_{limit}^2}{2 j_{limit}}
\end{pmatrix}}
$$

The third option for the value of $a_{limit}$ stands out for being so much longer than all the other expressions in the values of the limit-variables. Can it be condensed any? Is there a better way to write it? As-is, it feels very unsatisfying.

Comment: There are a large number of incredibly basic algebraic steps that could be made to your expression (expanding powers of monomials, factoring common factors, distributing roots over products, etc.); these will obviously make what you have look much simpler.  Whether at the end of the day they will resolve the major ways in which your expression is complicated (the nested roots) is less clear.  I'm personally not inclined to go through the trouble of the tedious arithmetic to get to the potentially interesting part.

Comment: TLDR. if you want assistance, try stating your question conscisely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\,\displaystyle a = d \cdot \left(\frac{j}{2}\right)^2\,$ and $\,\displaystyle b = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \left(\frac{j^2}{2s}\right)^2\,$, then the expression (without the radical-free term at the end) is:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
x &= \sqrt[3]{a + \sqrt{a^2 − b^3}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt[3]{a + \sqrt{a^2 − b^3}}} \cdot \color{red}{\frac{\sqrt[3]{a - \sqrt{a^2 − b^3}}}{\sqrt[3]{a - \sqrt{a^2 − b^3}}}}
\\ &= \sqrt[3]{a + \sqrt{a^2 − b^3}} + \frac{ \bcancel{b}\,\sqrt[3]{a - \sqrt{a^2 − b^3}}}{\bcancel{\sqrt[3]{\cancel{a^2} - (\cancel{a^2} − b^3)}}}
\\ &= \sqrt[3]{a + \sqrt{a^2 − b^3}} + \sqrt[3]{a - \sqrt{a^2 − b^3}}
\end{align}
$$

Let $\,u,v = \sqrt[3]{a \pm \sqrt{a^2 − b^3}}\,$, then $\,uv = b\,$, and:

$$
\begin{align}
x^3 = (u+v)^3 &= u^3+v^3+3uv(u+v)
\\ &= \left(a + \cancel{\sqrt{a^2 − b^3}}\right) + \left(a - \cancel{\sqrt{a^2 − b^3}}\right) + 3b(u+v)
\\ &= 2a + 3 b x
\end{align}
$$

Therefore $\,x\,$ is a root of the depressed cubic $\,x^3 - 3bx - 2a = 0\,$, and the initial expression is in fact one form of [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano%27s_formula). Reverting to the original parameters, the equation is:

$$
x^3 - \cancel{3} \cdot \frac{1}{\cancel{3}} \cdot \left(\frac{j^2}{2s}\right)^2 x - 2 \cdot d \cdot \left(\frac{j}{2}\right)^2 = 0 \quad\iff\quad 4 s^2 \,x^3 - j^4 \,x - 2 d j^2s^2 = 0
$$

The latter is equivalent to the general depressed cubic, and there is no known formula simpler than the one that contains two cube roots (unless there are additional constraints on $d,j,s$).

Comment: Congratulation on taking up this question.

Comment: @NoChance Thanks. Thought that would be fair, since the OP put a lot of effort in *asking* the question.

Comment: @dxiv I can follow along with what you're doing in the first half, but I'm confused as to what's going on after you introduce $u$, $v$, and $x$. I understand each step individually - that is, the mathematical operations make sense - but I'm not sure how it connects to my question. What am I missing?

Comment: @Lawton You wrote that "*specifically, I'd like to condense the cube root portion and the inverse cube root portion into a single portion*". The expression you are asking about is what's labeled $\,x\,$ in my answer, which shows that $\,x\,$ is the root of a general depressed cubic equation. These equations have been studied extensively for hundreds of years, and the algebraic [solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) all involve *two* cube roots. Therefore it is not possible to "*condense ... into a single*" cube root, so the answer to your question is negative.

Comment: Ah, I understand now.

Comment: @dxiv Is the $c$ in the depressed-cubic equation supposed to be $2 a$?

Comment: @Lawton Yes, thanks for catching that. Corrected now.

Comment: @dxiv Technically, there is a way to solve the general cubic using _only a single cube root_. (It uses a Tschirnhausen transformation.) I'll give a second answer to this question within the day or so to illustrate.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Thanks for raising the point. Guess I should have been more careful with wording the "*it is not possible...*" part. What I really meant was "*it is not possible in a practical way...*". You are technically right, and I imagine that an appropriately chosen quadratic transformation could do that. It will be interesting to see the final form, I'd expect a few more square roots around.